# SQL query to retrieve data based on either emailid or userid

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, type-conversion

I have to write a query for a login page where the user can enter either emailid(varchar datatype) or userid(int datatype). How do I write a query for this without knowing the datatype of the input?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_stored_procedure   
@emailId nvarchar(50) = NULL,   
@userId int = NULL
AS   

SET NOCOUNT ON;  
IF (@emailId IS NOT NULL) AND (LEN(@emailId) > 0)
    SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE EmailId = @emailId
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE UserId = @UserId
GO
```

Comment: Error: Procedure or function 'GetLoginDetails' expects parameter '@userId', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Your input parameter should be of `varchar` type.
Then in your procedure use `ISNUMERIC` function to check for number. Have two queries based on that with IF statement in case if it is `int` or `varchar`.

```
DECLARE @userInput VARCHAR(50)
IF ISNUMERIC(@userInput) = 1 
BEGIN
-- Your query with userid
END
ELSE
BEGIN
-- Your query with emailid
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query it may help you.

```
 DECLARE @emailid varchar(250),@userid bigint
 set @emailid='A' 
 SET @userid=3

 select * from yourtable 
 where case when @emailid='A' THEN 'A' ELSE emailid END=@emailid
 AND  case when @userid=0 THEN 0 ELSE userid END=@userid
```

**Note:** You should pass 'A' as default value for email_id and 0 for userid or else you can pass your required input

Comment: you should use @dexter code.it gives desirable answer